# Errors blocking WP admin access and when attempting debugging in host Google Cloud Platform

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, wordpress, debug

Wordpress VM instance site in Google Cloud Platform is showing an error message which links to debug information, tried the steps in SDK from a tutorial, but not working, not experienced enough to understand. The message I get is ...

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'WP_DEBUG','
```

No idea what this is.
Cannot access WP admin or site at all. I received an email (with a recovery link that doesn't even work) - with lines of code extracted from a W3 Total Cache plugin, stating this was where the error occurred. This was exactly when the white screen issue started - as I was updating this plugin. I had checked compatibility first. I am guessing maybe while updating it was trying to do another scheduled task but this is only an amateur guess. This is the longest I have had a problem with sites. Tried many things, including deleting this plugin manually in -myphp which I can still access. No change. There are still folders associated with it in Filezilla but I am refused permissions to do anything in there, even if I knew what to do. I have minimal experience with brackets and opened the named file with the error in there - but once in there, not a clue what I am supposed to do.

Any help would be appreciated, I am not going to waste another 15 hours on this as I did yesterday!

[white screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZN5v.jpg)

Error defined in email:

```
When seeking help with this issue, you may be asked for some of the
following information:
WordPress version 5.5.5
Current theme: SetSail Child (version 1.3.2.1566033466)
Current plugin:  (version )
PHP version 7.0.33-0+deb9u11



Error Details
=============
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 733 of the file
/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/Minify_MinifiedFileRequestHandler.php.
Error message: Uncaught Error: Class 'W3TCL\Minify\Minify_Cache_File'
not found in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/Minify_MinifiedFileRequestHandler.php:733
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/Minify_MinifiedFileRequestHandler.php(297):
W3TC\Minify_MinifiedFileRequestHandler->_get_cache()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/CacheFlush_Locally.php(77):
W3TC\Minify_MinifiedFileRequestHandler->flush()
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/CacheFlush_Locally.php(87):
W3TC\CacheFlush_Locally->minifycache_flush(NULL)
#3 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287):
W3TC\CacheFlush_Locally->minifycache_flush_all(NULL)
#4 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311):
WP_Hook->apply_filters(1, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/CacheFlush_Locally.php(201):
do_action('w3tc_flush_all', NULL)
#7 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/CacheFlush.php(148):
```

Comment: Go to the directory `/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins`. Delete the directory `w3-total-cache`. Reboot your server.

Comment: I will try this ASAP and post later if it works. Thanks for your reply John sounds logical, hopefully it will work! Shayley

Comment: No. Unfortunately same errors as previously this is even after I deleted the listing in 'active plugins' table in myphp, example of the 'no permission' in Filezilla error: Error: rmdir /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/data/mediaconnect: permission denied   ---- So should I find a way to get permission or find other traces of it in myphp?

Comment: Permission for all plugins is listed as: drwxr-xr-x     I don't know what to do about this.

Comment: Warning: be careful with the second command. 1) `cd /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins` 2) `sudo rm -rf w3-total-cache`

Comment: In addition to deleting the plugin you also need to delete `wp-content/advanced-cache.php` as this is provided by W3 Total Cache as well.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will have to try to find every trace of W3 Total in mySQL in php admin as I still cannot get permissions to delete inside filezilla.

Comment: You need to SSH login to the instance and not use FileZilla.